# Search form input - Search "as you type" with HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have following search form in an HTML page on website built with Django:

```
<form method="get">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="q" id="id_q" placeholder="Search...">
</form>
```

I would like it to perform a search while typing (not having to press enter). I know we could use **onchange** or **onkeyup**, but I don't seem to be able to make it work.

The javascript at the bottom of the page is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("id_q").value = "{{query}}"
</script>
```

Edit: I saw that my search works without the Javascript part above, but I still need to press on Enter. What would be a simple script to launch the search "as you type" without pressing Enter?

Answer (score 0):

**once you `onchange` you can get your current values and send a API request or anything you want to do something like below-**

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const input = document.getElementById("id_q");
  input.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    let currentVal=e.target.value;
    // do anything with this value
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am really new to this. First, what do I put in the `onchange=""` ? Secondly, I saw that without my Javascript, the search works as well, but I still need to press Enter. Is there a simple way to just launch this search without pressing Enter?

Comment: @python1259 onchange work in the same way as you are expecting, when you type and release it automatically set that value as current value, so you don't need to put any enter key at all.

Comment: I have added `onkeyup="this.form.submit()"` in the <input> and that's already closer to what I need, but it submits and erases the field. Is there a way to keep the data that was being typed?

Comment: @python1259 This happens because the form's default behavior is to submit and refresh the page, so you need to use the event.preventDefault() to stop refreshing your page and this will keep your input field data.